# Windows 8 extend display without toolbar

Tags: windows-8, extended-desktop

Anyone got an idea how to extend display on windows 8 without the toolbar?

It works initially but as soon as I click on toolbar on screen 1 it displays on screen 2. This is not the desired behaviour as I'd prefer screen 2 to just be an extended display without the toolbar.

Image showing the two displays: [image: I blured the icons]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what your talking about.

Comment: @Ramhound Any suggestions?

Comment: What you want is not possible since your using Windows 8.

Comment: Sad smiley ;( very sad. Another brick to the wall of idiocy of windows 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on `Taskbar`, select `Properties`, under `Multiple displays` in the `Taskbar tab` remove the `Show taskbar on all displays selection`. Now you have no taskbar on extended displays.